# Wait on the Database Engine recovery handle failed!! SQL Server 2012 installation

Tags: sql-server-2012, sql-server-2012-express

Can someone please guide me on how to overcome the following error. I am trying to install SQL Server 2012 Express on my win7 32bit system. I had SQL Server 2008 R2 32 bit installed in this system, which was removed by the previous user (this is an official system (laptop) I am using).

Here is the log file generated after unsuccessful installation:

```
Overall summary:
  Final result:                  Failed: see details below
  Exit code (Decimal):           -2061893607
  Start time:                    2013-07-12 15:43:20
  End time:                      2013-07-12 15:55:46
  Requested action:              Install

Setup completed with required actions for features.
Troubleshooting information for those features:
  Next step for SQLEngine:       Use the following information to resolve the error, uninstall this feature, and then run the setup process again.


Machine Properties:
  Machine name:                  FSLTECYOUBRAJ
  Machine processor count:       4
  OS version:                    Windows 7
  OS service pack:               Service Pack 1
  OS region:                     United States
  OS language:                   English (United States)
  OS architecture:               x86
  Process architecture:          32 Bit
  OS clustered:                  No

Product features discovered:
  Product              Instance             Instance ID                    Feature                                  Language             Edition              Version         Clustered 

Package properties:
  Description:                   Microsoft SQL Server 2012 
  ProductName:                   SQL Server 2012
  Type:                          RTM
  Version:                       11
  SPLevel:                       0
  Installation location:         D:\New folder\MSI's\Excel\SQLEXPRWT_x86_ENU\x86\setup\
  Installation edition:          Express

Product Update Status:
  User selected not to include product updates.

User Input Settings:
  ACTION:                        Install
  ADDCURRENTUSERASSQLADMIN:      true
  AGTSVCACCOUNT:                 NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE
  AGTSVCPASSWORD:                *****
  AGTSVCSTARTUPTYPE:             Disabled
  ASBACKUPDIR:                   Backup
  ASCOLLATION:                   Latin1_General_CI_AS
  ASCONFIGDIR:                   Config
  ASDATADIR:                     Data
  ASLOGDIR:                      Log
  ASPROVIDERMSOLAP:              1
  ASSERVERMODE:                  MULTIDIMENSIONAL
  ASSVCACCOUNT:                  <empty>
  ASSVCPASSWORD:                 <empty>
  ASSVCSTARTUPTYPE:              Automatic
  ASSYSADMINACCOUNTS:            <empty>
  ASTEMPDIR:                     Temp
  BROWSERSVCSTARTUPTYPE:         Disabled
  CLTCTLRNAME:                   <empty>
  CLTRESULTDIR:                  <empty>
  CLTSTARTUPTYPE:                0
  CLTSVCACCOUNT:                 <empty>
  CLTSVCPASSWORD:                <empty>
  CLTWORKINGDIR:                 <empty>
  COMMFABRICENCRYPTION:          0
  COMMFABRICNETWORKLEVEL:        0
  COMMFABRICPORT:                0
  CONFIGURATIONFILE:             
  CTLRSTARTUPTYPE:               0
  CTLRSVCACCOUNT:                <empty>
  CTLRSVCPASSWORD:               <empty>
  CTLRUSERS:                     <empty>
  ENABLERANU:                    true
  ENU:                           true
  ERRORREPORTING:                true
  FEATURES:                      SQLENGINE
  FILESTREAMLEVEL:               0
  FILESTREAMSHARENAME:           <empty>
  FTSVCACCOUNT:                  <empty>
  FTSVCPASSWORD:                 <empty>
  HELP:                          false
  INDICATEPROGRESS:              false
  INSTALLSHAREDDIR:              C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\
  INSTALLSHAREDWOWDIR:           <empty>
  INSTALLSQLDATADIR:             <empty>
  INSTANCEDIR:                   C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\
  INSTANCEID:                    SQLEXPRESS2012
  INSTANCENAME:                  SQLEXPRESS2012
  ISSVCACCOUNT:                  NT AUTHORITY\Network Service
  ISSVCPASSWORD:                 <empty>
  ISSVCSTARTUPTYPE:              Automatic
  MATRIXCMBRICKCOMMPORT:         0
  MATRIXCMSERVERNAME:            <empty>
  MATRIXNAME:                    <empty>
  NPENABLED:                     0
  PID:                           *****
  QUIET:                         false
  QUIETSIMPLE:                   false
  ROLE:                          AllFeatures_WithDefaults
  RSINSTALLMODE:                 DefaultNativeMode
  RSSHPINSTALLMODE:              DefaultSharePointMode
  RSSVCACCOUNT:                  <empty>
  RSSVCPASSWORD:                 <empty>
  RSSVCSTARTUPTYPE:              Automatic
  SAPWD:                         *****
  SECURITYMODE:                  SQL
  SQLBACKUPDIR:                  <empty>
  SQLCOLLATION:                  SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
  SQLSVCACCOUNT:                 NT Service\MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS2012
  SQLSVCPASSWORD:                <empty>
  SQLSVCSTARTUPTYPE:             Automatic
  SQLSYSADMINACCOUNTS:           CADOMAIN\youbarajs
  SQLTEMPDBDIR:                  <empty>
  SQLTEMPDBLOGDIR:               <empty>
  SQLUSERDBDIR:                  <empty>
  SQLUSERDBLOGDIR:               <empty>
  SQMREPORTING:                  false
  TCPENABLED:                    0
  UIMODE:                        AutoAdvance
  UpdateEnabled:                 false
  UpdateSource:                  MU
  X86:                           false

  Configuration file:            C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20130712_154108\ConfigurationFile.ini

Detailed results:
  Feature:                       Database Engine Services
  Status:                        Failed: see logs for details
  Reason for failure:            An error occurred during the setup process of the feature.
  Next Step:                     Use the following information to resolve the error, uninstall this feature, and then run the setup process again.
  Component name:                SQL Server Database Engine Services Instance Features
  Component error code:          0x851A0019
  Error description:             Wait on the Database Engine recovery handle failed. Check the SQL Server error log for potential causes.
  Error help link:               http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkId=20476&ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&ProdVer=11.0.2100.60&EvtType=0xE53883A0%400xBE03358B%401306%4025&EvtType=0xE53883A0%400xBE03358B%401306%4025

  Feature:                       SQL Browser
  Status:                        Passed

  Feature:                       SQL Writer
  Status:                        Passed

  Feature:                       SQL Client Connectivity
  Status:                        Passed

  Feature:                       SQL Client Connectivity SDK
  Status:                        Passed

Rules with failures:

Global rules:

Scenario specific rules:

Rules report file:               C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20130712_154108\SystemConfigurationCheck_Report.htm
```

Comment: I also faced the same problem while installing sql server 2012.The solution given here worked for me: https://web.archive.org/web/20160313132045/http://www.superpctricks.com/2014/02/sql-install-error-database-engine-recovery-handle-failed.html

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Ok, after 6 hours of struggle and 'googling' I could finally get this work. The problem was due to some account name conflict. Here are the steps I followed to set it right

1) Un-installed the SQLserver

3) Re-installed it back with following changes

- In the server configuration section, I changed the account name
  details to "NT AUTHORITY/LOCALSERVICE" (during the installation process)

Please remember to set it as "NT AUTHORITY/NETWORKSERVICE" if LOCAL SERVICE is not allowed.

Comment: Install told me LOCAL SERVICE was not allowed.  NETWORK SERVICE worked for me.  Thanks for documenting your solution. Helped me loads.

Comment: "NT AUTHORITY\NETWORKSERVICE" was the solution for me

Comment: was able to add LOCAL SERVICE when installing on Windows Server 2012 R2 Essentials. This solution was so minute you could spend so many tries and so many hours on this. Thanks so much..

Comment: LOCAL and NETWORK both failed for me for some reason, but I created a service account and that worked perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is with the new account creation after Windows 8.1 Update 1 for me. If you are trying to install on Win8.1.1 try the instructions found [here](http://kalcik.net/2014/04/04/problems-with-the-installation-of-sql-server-2014-after-the-windows-8-1-update/)

Basically you need to reset the permissions on the default account. I remember someone having problems with creating new child accounts after this update as well.

Comment: I ran into this problem after Windows 8.1 Update 1. I did what was instructed at the end of the linked article. I then tried repairing the install but that failed. So I uninstalled before reinstalling and that worked as expected!

Comment: Yup I was in the same boat. If you've installed you pretty much have to fix the permissions and then start over.