# SQL Server 2012 Express Database Engine Service failed

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2012-express

I am currently taking a class for SQL. The class requires me to download SQL Server 2012 Express W/tools. I am have an issue with the download that is causing all sorts of problems and I am stumped. This part is not graded or anything, it is just to get it installed and my professor still has not gotten back to me.

When I complete the download it is completed but with errors. and gives a quick log saying

The following error has occurred:

> Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation.

Also it says that every install was successful except the **Database Engine Service** giving the error code: 0x84880001.

When I enter into the log files under **bootstrap/log** the error summary report reads as follows: http://pastebin.com/NEVGHGSv

I have been working on this trying to get it resolved for 9+ hours and have installed and re installed SQL Server 2012 Express a dozen times at least.

Things I have tried:

- Manually Start the instance, it wanted to start but then error'ed out and refused to run.
- Use a Named instance instead, this did not solve the problem.
- Check possible issues in good using error codes involving `MSSQLSERVER` that I found in the Event viewer to include, 17058, and 7034. some possible causes came up at [SQLServerCentral.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17613094/wait-on-the-database-engine-recovery-handle-failed-sql-server-2012-installatio) tried and failed, [StackOverflow post](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic962384-391-1.aspx) tried and failed.

If there is anything anybody can possibly see that I cannot the help would be appreciated. I am New to Stackoverflow and if there is something I may have missed in my post I will be monitoring it as much as I can.

Comment: Still unsure what the problem was and I even has some more tech savvy friends of mine rather puzzled, but I got it working today. I ended up doing a clean install of windows 7 and used Visual Studio 2012/SQL2014. The install went through like it is supposed to have no problems since.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to install by first uninstalling "Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Native Client" from "Control Panel > Uninstall a program". For some reason, that component had been installed months earlier, and the upgrade advisor never caught it as a problem. Still, the odd installation date caught my eye, and since someone else mentioned the installation began failing with that component, uninstalling allowed me to re-run SQL Server 2012 upgrade successfully after 3 or 4 previously failed attempts pretty much exactly as you described.

Comment: Gave this a try and did not work in my situation. The biggest problem now for my is that the database engine refuses to install but the rest of the install goes without a hitch.