# Unable to install Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Developer

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a problem with installing SQL Server 2012 (no matter which edition I choose).
Installation usually runs well, but near the end shows up an error:

[image: install error]

The help link points to not-existing article on MSDN page.
After I click OK button, the installation reaches it's end and shows up another window:

[image: installation failure]

After that I am able to start, for example SQL Management Studio, but cannot connect to database. Also services of SQL Server are stopped and I am not able to start them manually (any try throws an undefined error):

[image: sql services]

[image: starting error]

I tried complete reinstalling of SQL Server, cleaning registry entries, different editions of that software - none method helped. Also, I tried the .iso images of installation media on other computers - it worked well and installed without any errors.
My OS is Windows 8.1 x64.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Wait on the Database Engine recovery handle failed!! SQL Server 2012 installation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17613094/wait-on-the-database-engine-recovery-handle-failed-sql-server-2012-installatio)

Comment: Indeed, that helped me.

Comment: Glad I could be of help.