# SQL Installation Help...cannot fix Database Engine Error, Need remote assistance now

Tags: sql-server-2008r2-express

Have been using SQL Server 2008 R2 Express for years, and my db engine somehow got corrupt.
Installed/reinstalled, da da da...

I've got 2 days in now trying to fix known nagging error without success:

> Database Engine recovery handle failed

I am ready to pay for remote technical support now...

I've read and tried most of the support forum solutions on this, trying to change the server logon and am at a standstill...

Any idea whom I might call for support?

Thanks

jlm86

Comment: Express doesn't come with official MS support, so not sure who you'd call.  But check this thread if you haven't already.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17613094/wait-on-the-database-engine-recovery-handle-failed-sql-server-2012-installatio  best of luck!

Comment: freelancer sites might be a better target for this ;-)