# Error in installation of SQL SERVER 2012

Tags: sql-server-2012, windows-server-2008-r2

Error in installation of SQL SERVER 2012 on windows server 2008 R2 "error in the expected recovery driver database engine"

Comment: possible duplicate of [Wait on the Database Engine recovery handle failed!! SQL Server 2012 installation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17613094/wait-on-the-database-engine-recovery-handle-failed-sql-server-2012-installatio)

Comment: Thank you Mihai, but I already solved the problem, during installation, when you configure the server, there are problems with Windows Server 2008 R2 if you put the SQL Server Database Enginee service with NT AUTHORITY \ SYSTEM goes wrong. We must put NT AUTHORITY \ Network Service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem, during installation, when you configure the server, there are problems with Windows Server 2008 R2 if you put the SQL Server Database Enginee service with NT AUTHORITY \ SYSTEM goes wrong. We must put NT AUTHORITY \ Network Service.